# Google spreadsheet : impose formatting within constructed string in a cell

Tags: google-sheets

I want to be able to impose the formatting of a string that is part of a string concatenation within a cell formula, ideally depending on the value of another cell. Something like :

```
="This is " & FORMATSTRING(IF(A1,"bold", "normal"),"bold text")
```

Can I do this in Google sheets ? If yes, how ?

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data. Enter textual descriptions in cells to tell what you want in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

That cannot be done with a [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions), because custom functions cannot format cells. They can only return a value or an array of values that is used when evaluating the formula they are part of.

You can format cells, but not partial cell contents, with a [conditional formatting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/78413) custom formula rule custom formula rule like this:

`=$A1`

To format partial cell contents programmatically, you need a script such as [formatText](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/157400260?msgid=157852265).

Answer (score 1):

[image: concat]
It is not very easy but it can be done without a script, taking advantage of the very high unicode code like 119808 for a bold A. See this [test sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w-IRYYuWew4ibcOfgRQOoi2irKR88ex8pVqALJO-ppk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hmm, after a cursory search, it is possible to do this with italics and italic bold. So it would be possible then to use a custom function. Though is it worth using these Unicode characters?

Comment: @David Tan  I think it would be difficult to pilot the script based on another cell